# Convert date in vector to Excel date number (R)

Tags: r, excel, date

I have a vector of date values:

```
dates=c("43018","43343","42272","06/27/17","01/10/18","10/11/18")
```

This is a mixture of actual dates and the Excel number-value of dates (ie: number of days since January 1, 1900).  I want to convert all of these values to the Excel format of dates, so we would have an output that looks like the following:

```
dates
[1]  "43018"   "43343"   "42272"   "42913"    "43110"    "43384"
```

My goal is to take these values and subtract them from another vector with an equal number of date values that are all the same to get an age of each observation.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - use the "janitor" library and the excel_numeric_to_date function.

Badda bing badda boom.